# Passing data from laravel blade to vue id error

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, uuid

When I pass my id property, which is a UUID, to a Vue component from my blade it seems to be passing it as a number. So if my UUID is 26c2c4ef-9aa0-6894-669f-1f502b0f647e, Vue is getting this as 26, or if it starts with a letter, Vue returns 0. I'm really confused as to why this is. My blade code is the following:

`<my-component :data="{{ json_encode($data) }}"></my-component>`

If I use `<?php ddd($data); ?>` in the blade I can see that the correct ID is returned. But then if I console log my Vue prop out I get just the number. Has anyone experienced this before? I am pretty new to Laravel and have no idea why this is happening.

Update: After running the following in the blade `<?php ddd(json_encode($data)) ?>` this is returning the id as the incorrect int, so it looks like this is where the problem occurs.

Comment: Another point which is confusing me is that this only happens to my id property. I have other UUID properties such as role_id and these are returned as the correct UUID

Comment: I have fixed this by setting the id in the casts array of the model to string